# IntegrityError at /notes/add NOT NULL constraint failed: notes_note.created

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

I have a problem when I do add function in django2 cant add new post And this code

IntegrityError at /notes/add
NOT NULL constraint failed: notes_note.created

thes views

```
    def note_add(request):

    # form = NoteForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = NoteForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user = request.user
            new_form.save()
            return redirect('/notes')
    else:

        form = NoteForm()

    context={
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, 'add.html', context )
```

Comment: IntegrityError at /notes/add
NOT NULL constraint failed: notes_note.created

Comment: idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Did not dv, but please copy code in the question, do not post images of code.

Comment: @memeal: can you share the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set a default for the `created` field in your `Note` model. As a consequence, no value is filled in, hence the error: You can set the [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) to `True` to automatically set this to the timestamp when the object was created:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    # …
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Normally it is better to alter the `.instance` wrapped in the form, and let the form `.save()` the model. This is especially useful if you (later) add a many-to-many relation to your `Note` model, since the form handles this logic in a more transparent way:

```
def note_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('/notes')
    else:
        form = NoteForm()
    context={
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'add.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the problem